# In genric list values passing to xml . How to perform Insert and update operations sql?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, xml, generic-list

[image]Scenario : 1.Form having gridview with 5 records. (binding records FROM database) 2.one more record am selecting to autocomplete and then adding to gridview.  3.next deleted one more record from that gridview then passing values to DB through XML. my xml code like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfLanuageInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SpokenLanuageInfo>
    <LanguageId>154</LanguageId>  
  </SpokenLanuageInfo>
  <SpokenLanuageInfo>
    <LanguageId>46</LanguageId>
  </SpokenLanuageInfo>
  <SpokenLanuageInfo>
    <LanguageId>53</LanguageId>
  </SpokenLanuageInfo>
</ArrayOfLanuageInfo>

here one recoded am deleted ,one record added so how to do ??
 -deleted record should remove from table
 -new record insert into table

Stored Procedure like this : 
// here am deleting all records based on id every time and then inserting table so i don't want like this //
 DELETE FROM [dbo].LANGUAGE WHERE  [HOSPITAL_ID]=@HOSPITAL_ID

                                  INSERT INTO [dbo].LANGUAGE
                                  (
                                     HOSPITAL_ID, LANGUAGE_ID
                                  )
                                 SELECT  @HOSPITAL_ID,LanguageId
                           FROM   
                              OPENXML(@XmlHandleSAVELANGUAG,'/ArrayOfLanuageInfo/LanuageInfo',2)  
                                   WITH   
                                    (  LanguageId INT )   
                    END
```

Comment: BTW this appears to be a question more about SQL rather than ASP.Net.
It might be worth editing the question to make it more clear what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal candidate for the use of a SQL MERGE.
It allows you to insert/update/delete based on matching criteria in a single statement.

Check the [Microsoft Technet reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx) for further information.

Edit: Here's some example code for using SQL MERGE alongside OPENXML

```
declare @idoc int;
declare @inputXml xml = N'
<data>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>first</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>second</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>5</id>
        <name>fifth</name>
    </item>
</data>';
-- idoc is the xml representation we work with
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @inputXml;


-- setup our table to merge
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (id int primary key, name varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @myTable (id, name)
VALUES 
    (1, 'one'),
    (2, 'two'),
    (3, 'three');

SELECT * FROM @myTable

-- merge the selected XML content into myTable
-- if we match on ID, update the name
-- if we don't find a match in the table, insert the entry in the XML
-- if we don't find a match in the XML, delete the entry in the table

MERGE INTO @myTable AS Target
USING 
    OPENXML(@idoc, 'data/item', 2) 
    WITH (id int 'id/text()', name nvarchar(50) 'name/text()')
    AS source
ON Target.id = source.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET name = source.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (id, name) VALUES (id, name)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;

SELECT * FROM @myTable
```

Comment: Edited the answer to include example source. Let me know if I can clarify anything!